# How do I find the last occurence of a date in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a dataframe containing multiple events for every date (the events are ordered by date). It is easy to find the row number of the first occurence of a date using `match()`.
Now I am looking for a way to find the last occurence of a date.

Comment: try doing the `match` on the reverse vector i.e. `length(v) + 1 - match(yourdate, rev(v))`  or use `tail(which(v == yourdate), 1)`

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you posted a reproducible example as well as what you expect the result to look like.

Comment: `x <- c( 1, 2, 3, 5 , 3 , 4, 3, 7, 8 )`   then  `max( which( x == 3 ) )`